# List of Anonymous objects?

Tags: c#, list, anonymous-types

I have a class using the List class.  When attempting to set up the Add function to add my anonymous type, all I get is errors.

I've been searching for hours and as best I can tell, every example I've seen is doing the same thing.  So I don't understand what's wrong.

```
class fileHistory<Object> : List<Object>
{
    public new void Add(DateTime ts, int st)
    {
        base.Add( new { timeStamp = ts; status = st;} );
    }
}
```

Comment: What errors do you get?

Comment: Are you trying to declare a generic type or not? You've use the identifier Object as a generic type parameter, which is very confusing.

Comment: This should be a `List<dynamic>`, not `List<object>`. You won't be able to retrieve the `timeStamp` and `status` attributes later, because you can't cast to your anonymous type. Or simply make it a named type, no reason to make it anonymous.

Comment: It's not very anonymous if you have to name it, is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a generic declaration in your class definition, and you also need to change semicolons to commas:

```
public class fileHistory : List<Object>
{
    public new void Add(DateTime ts, int st)
    {
        base.Add( new { timeStamp = ts, status = st} );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Right, you can overwrite (not polymorphism! check I used the word *overwrite* instead of *override*) `List<T>.Add(T)` method, but I believe that you could solve your issue using composition instead of inheritance and your code will work flawlessly:

```
class fileHistory
{
    private readonly List<object> _log = new List<object>();

    public void Add(DateTime ts, int st)
    {
         _log.Add( new { timeStamp = ts; status = st;} );
    }
}
```

BTW, I see three design flaws here:

1. Anonymous types aren't meant to your use case. If you are adding objects with these two properties and you do it in a concrete use case like yours, **maybe you're using anonymous types because of your laziness of designing a class with 2 properties??? ;)**
2. Because of #1, why you would create a list of `objects` using a generic list? It defeats the entire purpose of generics!!
3. I find a bad design decision hidding `Add` of `List<T>`. Use composition instead of inheritance in these cases. Also, I don't know why you're using identifier re-using with `new` keyword when C# supports method **overloading**. In `List<T>` there's no overload of `Add` with your input parameters...

My advise is: code isn't fancier because of using fancy syntactic sugar provided by C#. Sometimes you don't need it, and honestly, I believe this is the case.

### For those who're worried about LINQ...

Any class might or might not implement `IEnumerable<T>`. The whole `fileHistory` class can be iterated with `foreach` or LINQ and its extension methods implementing `IEnumerable<T>`:

```
// Check that I dropped the lazy approach of using 
// anonymous types!!
class fileHistory : IEnumerable<FileLog>
{
    private readonly List<FileLog> _log = new List<FileLog>();

    public IEnumerator<FileLog> GetEnumerator() 
    {
         return _log.GetEnumerator();
    }


    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return _log.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public void Add(DateTime ts, int st)
    {
         _log.Add(new FileLog { timeStamp = ts; status = st;} );
    }
}
```

...and now some class like this can be iterated even when using composition instead of inheritance:

```
new fileHistory().Where(log => log.DateTime < DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: You're correct that I was looking to do it this way avoid having to create an additional class just for two properties.  It seemed like a lot of extra overhead.  I've done tutorials and such in the past but this will be my first program with an actual purpose.

Comment: Something happened on my end and I thought my last comment was lost so I retyped (most of) it.  Then when I bumped the submit button, I saw my double post.  Since I couldn't delete the second one, I figured I'd at least edit it.

Comment: @doni49 Yeah, keep it simple!

Answer (score 0):

```
class fileHistory<Object> : List<Object>
{
    public new void Add(DateTime ts, int st)
    {
        // That's how it's supposed to be
        base.Add(new { timeStamp = ts, status = st });
    }
}
```

Hope I've helped!